# Flutter : i want to get the value after scanning the NFC card

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, nfc

I want to get the same value from NFC card. i bought nfc card reader for my information system(using web).
and i use phone with NFC reader, when i scan with nfc card reader that i bought it's give me value 1458435129. but when i scan using my phone that i programmed its give me this response

```
{
nfca: 
    {
        identifier: [57, 244, 237, 86], 
        atqa: [4, 0], 
        maxTransceiveLength: 253, 
        sak: 8, 
        timeout: 618
    }, 
mifareclassic: 
    {
        identifier: [57, 244, 237, 86], 
        blockCount: 64, 
        maxTransceiveLength: 253, 
        sectorCount: 16, 
        size: 1024, 
        timeout: 618, 
        type: 0
    }, 
ndefformatable: 
    {
        identifier: [57, 244, 237, 86]
    }
}
```

where the value 1458435129 that i get from scanner that i bought come from?

Comment: Both values (value and identifier) can be identical, the first one is the integer value and the other is the four byte code one. Search for a byte array to integer method in Dart and compare the results. Sometimes you need to reverse the byte array before convert to integer.